# spark streaming job error out when insert rdd to S3 : InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand

Tags: scala, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, spark-streaming

Hi I am trying to save rdd as parquet files to S3 from spark streaming job like this:

```
someStream.foreachRDD { rdd =>
    {
        val data = sqlContext.createDataFrame(rdd)
        data.show()

        data
            .repartition(data("date"), data("hour"))
            .write
            .format("parquet")
            .mode(SaveMode.Append)
            .option("mergeSchema", "false")
            .option("mapreduce.fileoutputcommitter.algorithm.version", "2")
            .partitionBy("date", "hour")
            .save(s3Url)
    }
}
```

However, there is always a InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand Error which error out the whole streaming job, which looks like this:

> 2017-03-22 20:10:23,909 [streaming-job-executor-0] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand
>   - Aborting job. java.lang.InterruptedException
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998)
>           at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218)
>           at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:623)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1890)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1903)
>           at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1923)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:143)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand$$anonfun$run$1.apply(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:57)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:115)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:60)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:58)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:74)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:115)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:136)
>           at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:133)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:114)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:86)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:86)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.write(DataSource.scala:510)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:211)
>           at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:194)
>           at com.ticketnetwork.edwstream.jobs.performer.PerformerStreaming$$anonfun$makePerformerProgram$6.apply(PerformerStreaming.scala:251)
>           at com.ticketnetwork.edwstream.jobs.performer.PerformerStreaming$$anonfun$makePerformerProgram$6.apply(PerformerStreaming.scala:228)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream$$anonfun$foreachRDD$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3.apply(DStream.scala:627)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:51)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.DStream.createRDDWithLocalProperties(DStream.scala:415)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply$mcV$sp(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.dstream.ForEachDStream$$anonfun$1.apply(ForEachDStream.scala:50)
>           at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:192)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.Job.run(Job.scala:39)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(JobScheduler.scala:247)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:247)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler$$anonfun$run$1.apply(JobScheduler.scala:247)
>           at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
>           at org.apache.spark.streaming.scheduler.JobScheduler$JobHandler.run(JobScheduler.scala:246)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2017-03-22 20:10:23,998 [pool-4-thread-1] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus - SparkListenerBus has
>   already stopped! Dropping event
>   SparkListenerStageCompleted(org.apache.spark.scheduler.StageInfo@7dae0bac)
>   2017-03-22 20:10:24,001 [pool-4-thread-1] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.scheduler.LiveListenerBus - SparkListenerBus has
>   already stopped! Dropping event
>   SparkListenerJobEnd(23,1490213423999,JobFailed(org.apache.spark.SparkException:
>   Job 23 cancelled because SparkContext was shut down)) 2017-03-22
>   20:10:24,058 [Executor task launch worker-0] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl - Error in TaskCompletionListener
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Block broadcast_35 not found
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$1.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:288)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$1.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:288)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.unlock(BlockInfoManager.scala:287)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseLock(BlockManager.scala:630)
>           at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$releaseLock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:210)
>           at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$releaseLock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:210)
>           at org.apache.spark.TaskContext$$anon$1.onTaskCompletion(TaskContext.scala:123)
>           at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:97)
>           at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:95)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>           at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:95)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2017-03-22 20:10:24,062 [Executor task launch worker-2] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl - Error in TaskCompletionListener
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Block broadcast_35 not found
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$1.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:288)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager$$anonfun$1.apply(BlockInfoManager.scala:288)
>           at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:121)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.unlock(BlockInfoManager.scala:287)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseLock(BlockManager.scala:630)
>           at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$releaseLock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:210)
>           at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$releaseLock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:210)
>           at org.apache.spark.TaskContext$$anon$1.onTaskCompletion(TaskContext.scala:123)
>           at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:97)
>           at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl$$anonfun$markTaskCompleted$1.apply(TaskContextImpl.scala:95)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
>           at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:48)
>           at org.apache.spark.TaskContextImpl.markTaskCompleted(TaskContextImpl.scala:95)
>           at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:99)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:274)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2017-03-22 20:10:24,078 [Executor task launch worker-0] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 116.0 in stage
>   56.0 (TID 572) java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
>           at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
>           at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:646)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 2017-03-22 20:10:24,078 [Executor task launch worker-2] ERROR
>   org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 117.0 in stage
>   56.0 (TID 573) java.util.NoSuchElementException: None.get
>           at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:347)
>           at scala.None$.get(Option.scala:345)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockInfoManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockInfoManager.scala:343)
>           at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.releaseAllLocksForTask(BlockManager.scala:646)
>           at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:281)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

who has any ideas what caused this error?

Thank a lot in advance!

Comment: this error will not populate at first, it will be there after the streaming job saved some parquet files to S3

Comment: And this error will be gone if I remove repartition and partition part of the code. But I really do need to write data in the scope of date and hour.

Comment: any luck with this?